# Recursion seems to iterate one last time how can I fix this code?

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

I am attempting to check if a string is a palindrome or not( reads the same forwards and backwards )

I am having trouble understanding why the output is throwing the error that the variable has not been assigned after the code that says it has been assigned. I have a base case and a recursive case.

I also need to use only one return.

```py
def is_palindrome(s)
    if len(s)<=1: # if we have reached the end of the string
        print("is palindrome")
        palindrome = True
        print("set palindrome to true")
        
    elif len(s)>1:
        print("length not 1, checking again")
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            print("leftmost = rightmost")
            newstring = s[1:]
            newstring = newstring[:-1]
            s = newstring
            is_palindrome(s)
        else: 
            print("not palindrome")
            palindrome = False
        
    return palindrome
```

Output:

```
length not 1, checking again
leftmost = rightmost
length not 1, checking again
leftmost = rightmost
length not 1, checking again
leftmost = rightmost
is palindrome
set palindrome to true
```

Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):   
    line 16, in <module>
            print(is_palindrome(s))   
    line 134, in is_palindrome
            is_palindrome(s)   
    line 134, in is_palindrome
            is_palindrome(s)   
    line 139, in is_palindrome
            return palindrome UnboundLocalError: local variable 'palindrome' referenced before assignment
```

EDIT:
I now have this code however it seems as though it is returning true regardless

CODE:

```
palindrome = True
#BASE CASE
if len(s)>1:
    print("length not 1, checking again")
    if s[0] == s[-1]:
        print("leftmost = rightmost")
        newstring = s[1:]
        newstring = newstring[:-1]
        s = newstring
        is_palindrome(s)
    else: 
        print("not palindrome")
        palindrome = False
    
return palindrome
```

OUTPUT:

```
length not 1, checking again
leftmost = rightmost
length not 1, checking again
leftmost = rightmost
length not 1, checking again
not palindrome
True
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code fragment that you provide does not yield the output that you claim.

Comment: Please update your question with the full code of your function, plus the sample call that produces the output, plus the full error traceback. Future new programmers will need to see all that to fully understand what is going wrong.

Comment: There is more than enough to go on here.  The OP is never reaching the assignment, so the variable needs to be set outside the `if` or it needs to be set in an `else`.

Comment: Are you forced to do recursion? The entire palindrome check could be written in one line of code: `return s == s[::-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're assuming the `palindrome` variable is carried throughout the recursion, but it is a different piece of data each time recursion starts. So if you only follow the very first layer:

```py
def is_palindrome(s)
    if len(s)<=1: # if we have reached the end of the string
    #    print("is palindrome")
    #    palindrome = True
    #    print("set palindrome to true")
        
    elif len(s)>1:
        print("length not 1, checking again")
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            print("leftmost = rightmost")
            newstring = s[1:]
            newstring = newstring[:-1]
            s = newstring
            is_palindrome(s)
    #    else: 
    #        print("not palindrome")
    #        palindrome = False
        
    return palindrome
```

you get this. I commented out everything that doesn't run on the first layer, as you can see `palindrome` is never set. To accomplish what you want, I would take the line:

```py
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            print("leftmost = rightmost")
            newstring = s[1:]
            newstring = newstring[:-1]
            s = newstring
            is_palindrome(s)
```

and write it like this:

```py
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            print("leftmost = rightmost")
            newstring = s[1:]
            newstring = newstring[:-1]
            s = newstring
            palindrome = is_palindrome(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A key problem is this line:

```
is_palindrome(s)
```

You *know* `is_palindrome()` returns a value, but you've ignored it.  That returned value you ignored is key to solving the problem.  Here's a simplified logic for the problem:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    palindrome = False  # assume not a palindrome

    if len(s) <= 1:  # we have reached a minimal string
        palindrome = True  # it's palindrome
    elif s[0] == s[-1]:  # if leftmost == rightmost
        palindrome = is_palindrome(s[1:-1])  # recurse on "inner" string

    return palindrome

if is_palindrome("9609457639843489367549069"):
    print("is palindrome")
```

Since this code doesn't handle case, white space and punctuation, it's not as useful for language palindromes as it is for things like numeric palindromes.